# Eating commands

Tags: macros

I don't understand why this code behaves as it does:

```
\newcommand{\f}{f}% food
\newcommand{\s}{}% stop eating
\newcommand{\h}[1]{h}% hide food
\newcommand{\e}[1]{% eat
  \ifx\f#1
    e
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}

% f represents food
% e represents eaten food
% [v] means it works as expected
% [x] means it doesn't

% [v] Eat food
[\e\f]% [e]

% [v] Stop eating
[\e\s\f]% [f]

% [v] Hide food
[\h\f]% [h]

% [x] Eat hidden food
[\e\h\f]% [hf]
% I expected [h]
```

I would've expected `[\e\h\f]` → `[\h\f]` → `[h]`. What did I miss?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You needed `[\e{\h\f}]` so `\e` captures `\h\f` and not just `\h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `\show#1` to your definition of `\h`

```
 \newcommand{\h}[1]{\show#1h}%
```

you will see that in your last case the argument of `\h` is not the `\f` but the `\fi`.

You should better move the output behind the `\fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\f}{f}% food
\newcommand{\s}{}% stop eating
\newcommand{\h}[1]{h}% hide food
\newcommand{\e}[1]{% eat
  \ifx\f#1\relax
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
  \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
  \fi
  {e}%
  {#1}%
}

% f represents food
% e represents eaten food
% [v] means it works as expected
% [x] means it doesn't

% [v] Eat food
[\e\f]% [e]

% [v] Stop eating
[\e\s\f]% [f]

% [v] Hide food
[\h\f]% [h]

% [x] Eat hidden food
[\e\h\f]% [hf]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you very clear answer :) Just one questions: Why do you use `\relax` after the `\ifx` but comments after `}`?

Comment: I used `\relax` after the `\ifx` to be sure that the test ends there -- a comment wouldn't stop it if the argument is empty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but I couldn't resist writing one of my overlong answers.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional `\ifx` compares the following two tokens and returns true if they are the same as far as `\show` is concerned. So two identical characters (by character code and category code), or two macros having the same status with respect to `\long` (and `\protected` if e-TeX is used) and the same first level expansion, or the same TeX primitive (one or both can be control sequences `\let` to the primitive). A control sequence `\let` to a character will be considered the same as the character.

In the case of `\e\h\f`, `\e` finds its argument to be `\h`, so TeX replaces the first two tokens and gets

```
\ifx\f\h•e•\else\h•\fi\f
```

(here `•` denotes a space token). The test returns false, so TeX removes everything up to and including the matching `\else`. What remains at the next stage is

```
\h•\fi\f
```

and now `\h` finds its argument to be `\fi` (space tokens are ignored when looking for an undelimited argument), and the next stage is

```
h\f
```

Then TeX typesets `h`, expands `\f` that prints `f` and warns about an incomplete conditional, because there's no `\fi` any more:

```
\end occurred when \ifx on line 12 was incomplete
```

(the line number will of course be different).

On the contrary, `\e\s\f` will become

```
\ifx\f\s•e•\else\s•\fi\f
```

and then

```
\s•\fi\f
```

Since the expansion of `\s` is empty, you get

```
•\fi\f
```

and the space is typeset, the `\fi` is expanded (producing nothing, but keeping TeX happy about the count of conditional) and `\f` produces an ‘f’. Indeed, the output of `[\e\s\f]` is

> [ f]

With `\e\f` the replacement gives

```
\ifx\f\f•e•\else\f•\fi
```

and the test returns true. In this case, TeX just removes the `\ifx` and the test tokens; the next stage is so

```
•e•\else\f•\fi
```

so “space e space” is printed; then `\else` removes everything up to the matching `\fi`. Indeed, the output of `[\e\f]` is

> [ e ]

You should be more careful about spurious spaces and also pushing `\else` and `\fi` out of the way.

Ulrike's solution is good, and no space is added. However, if you want to have a fully expandable macro, do

```
\newcommand{\e}[1]{% eat
  \ifx\f#1%
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
  \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
  \fi
  {e}%
  {#1}%
}
```

but be sure to provide a non empty argument to `\e`. A different strategy is to compare the tokens with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\e}{m}
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \f #1 { e } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\f}{f}% food
\newcommand{\s}{}% stop eating
\newcommand{\h}[1]{h}% hide food
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\e}{m}
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \f #1 { e } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

% f represents food
% e represents eaten food

% Eat food
[\e\f]% [e]

% Stop eating
[\e\s\f]% [f]

% Hide food
[\h\f]% [h]

% Eat hidden food
[\e\h\f]% [h]

\end{document}
```