# Moving past the next group - `\hop\thing{\args}` → `\thing{\args}\hop`

Tags: macros

This is a followup question to [Eating commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258868/eating-commands/258876?noredirect=1) (where I got the code for `\e` which I am trying to adapt to make `\ep` work.

`\e` rewrites the next token into `e` if it is `\f` and leaves it alone otherwise.

`\ep` is supposed to do the same thing but if the next token is a `\h`, then it should skip it and then try to rewrite the next token. The only thing I managed to do is to rewrite `\ep\h\f` → `\h\ep\f` when what I want is `\ep\h\f` → `\h\f\ep`.

`\epb` manages to achieve `\epb\h\f` → `\h\f\epb` by adding an extra argument but it fails because `\epb\h{\f\f}` → `\h\f\f\epb` (or so it seems) instead of `\epb\h{\f\f}` → `\h{\f\f}\epb`.

Is there some way to fix that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\f}{f}% food
\newcommand{\s}{}% stop eating
\newcommand{\h}[1]{h}% hide food

\newcommand{\e}[1]{% eat
  \ifx\f#1%
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
  \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
  \fi
  {e}%
  {#1}%
}

\newcommand{\ep}[1]{% eat past (hidden food)
  \ifx\f#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
  \fi
  {e}%
  {%
    \ifx\h#1%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
    \fi
    {#1\ep}%
    {#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\epb}[2]{% eat past (hidden food) bis
  \ifx\f#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
  \fi
  {e#2}%
  {%
    \ifx\h#1%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo 
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo 
    \fi
    {#1#2\ep}%
    {#1#2}%
  }%
}

\makeatother

% f represents food
% e represents eaten food
% [v] means it works as expected
% [x] means it doesn't

% [v] Eat food
[\e\f]% [e]

% [v] Stop eating
[\e\s\f]% [f]

% [v] Hide food
[\h\f]% [h]

% [v] Eat hidden food
[\e\h\f]% [h]

% [v] Eat past hidden food
[\e\h\f\f]% hf

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\ep\h\f\f]% hff
% I expected he

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\epb\h\f\f]% he

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\epb\h{\f\f}\f]% hfe
% I expected he
```

Comment: Why not `{#1{#2}\ep}` instead of `{#1#2\ep}`?

Comment: @Manuel: Nice! That fixes `\e\h\f\f` → `\h\f\e\f` but apparently not `\e\h\f\h\f\f` → `\h\f\h\f\e\f`.

Comment: That doesn't work, because it should be `{#1{#2}\epb}` rather than `\ep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With expl3, but completely doable with plain (La)TeX macros.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \ep { m }
 { \xavierm_eat:N #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \xavierm_eat:N #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { \f } { \xavierm_eat_f:  }
    { \h } { \xavierm_eat_h:n }
   }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \xavierm_eat_f: { e }
\cs_new:Npn \xavierm_eat_h:n #1 { \h { #1 } \ep }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\f{f}% food
\newcommand*\s{}% stop eating
\newcommand*\h[1]{h}% hide food

\begin{document}
% f represents food
% e represents eaten food
% [v] means it works as expected
% [x] means it doesn't

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\ep\h\f\f]% hff
% I expected he

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\ep\h\f\f]% he

% [x] Eat past hidden food
[\ep\h{\f\f}\f]% hfe
% I expected he
\end{document}
```